# Iterate string of numbers with double number

Tags: python

I have number 746342 and i'm trying to get the list like this: `[700000, 40000, 6000, 300, 40, 2]`.
But when i'm trying to make the following:

```
def expanded_form(num):
    row = str(num).strip()
    row_2 = ([int(i) * 10**(len(row)-row.index(i)-1) for i in row])
    print(row_2)

expanded_form(746342)
```

i'm getting `[700000, 40000, 6000, 300, 40000, 2]`.

How to iterate second `"4"` separately, without giving it the value of the first `"4"`?

Thanks!

Comment: "enumerate" can provide a tuple of index and character of a string when using a for-loop or list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) turns an iterable into an iterator of `(index, value)` tuples. It both works on duplicates and is faster than `index`!

```
[int(d) * 10**(len(row)-i-1) for i, d in enumerate(row)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:-**

```
number=746342
res=[]
power=0
while number!=0:
    remainder=(number%10)*pow(10,power)
    number=number//10
    res.append(remainder)
    power+=1
print(res[::-1])
```

**Output:-**

```
[700000, 40000, 6000, 300, 40, 2]
```